# How to check for exception when pinging network

Tags: vb.net, exception

I have looked at a lot of documentation on how exception handling works and I believe I should be using unstructured exception handling but unfortunately I can't get it to work.

Code:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping((TextBox1.Text), 1000) = False Then
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=" & TextBox1.Text)
    End If
End If
```

Error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException' occurred in System.dll
```

Essentially I want it to ping the website that has been put in the textbox and if it can't ping it to perform a google search. I am not sure if this is the best way of going about doing this?

Comment: learn how to structure try/catch...  in VB, `Begin Try` .... `End Try`

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before settling on them.

Comment: I have tried to learn try and catch and have also tried inputting it and I am getting the same error unfortunately, and sorry about the tags. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Keep `On Error Resume Next` for VB6/VBA (and even then, it's usually a bad practice), and use `Try/Catch`. It's network stuff, it breaks by definition - your code just needs to gracefully handle network errors, and the idiomatic way to do this is with `Try/Catch` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely get rid of the legacy `On Error` approach.

Here's a possible way to use `Try/Catch/Finally` in your scenario:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    Dim result As Boolean = True
    Try
        result = My.Computer.Network.Ping(TextBox1.Text, 1000)
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        If result = False Then
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
        Else
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=" & TextBox1.Text)
        End If
    End Try
End If
```

Comment: That's great thank you for the example it doesn't redirect to the website unfortunately when the address is put in but now I have that great example I will see if I can fix this. Thank you! :)